# AWS DynamoDB Search on field contains comma separated value

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS DynamoDB NoSQL Database as back-end provider for my mobile application. We have one table it has field that contains comma separated value.

Using Mobile SDK in android platform I want to search on that field. Using Query or Scan API. I asked the same question to the support team of AWS. But They said that the it might be not correct way to store the data. The correct way suppose to store the multiple item into the same table.

Anybody have any idea how to search or query on field?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check my answer in this question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34349180/2811189 you have similar situation.

Comment: Thanks for the help:)