# ValidationException with Indexing stringSet in Vogels for DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

Here is my model definition:

```
var Notification = vogels.define('Notification', {
    tableName: 'notification',
    hashKey: 'notification_id',
    rangeKey: 'createdAt',
    timestamps: true,
    schema: {
        notification_id : vogels.types.uuid(),
        badge: joi.number().integer(),
        delay: joi.number(),
        action: joi.string(),
        body: joi.string(),
        tags: vogels.types.stringSet()
    },
    indexes: [{
        hashKey : 'tags',
        rangeKey: 'createdAt',
        name : 'TagsIndex',
        type : 'global'
    }]
});
```

However, when I want to create this table, I get the following error:

```
Error creating tables:  { [ValidationException: Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]]
  message: 'Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: Thu May 12 2016 14:06:44 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  requestId: 'c775c989-c723-4d55-b319-731230a5991b',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0 }
```

The problem is with the `index`. I remove that, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurred because you **cannot use SET** data type with Hash/Hash-Range keys.

Only String, Number, and Binary data type can be used for Keys that is what error is suggesting.

[Documentation Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeySchemaElement.html) clearly mention that we cannot use set.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Fair enough. How do I then index tags so I can search for them? I don't want to use `scan` because that then reads the entire DB.

Comment: @Kousha, here is one of my answer which might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/34349180/2811189