# Amazon DynamoDB with 'OR' condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm just starting with the amazon dynamoDB and I have to create a no-sql db structure like this,

```
-posts
    -postId1
        -tags
            1:A
            2:B
            3:C
        -text:Hello

    -postId2
        -tags
            1:B
            2:D
        -text:How are you?

    -postId3
        -tags   
            1:A
            2:C
        -text:Hello World
```

Now, I want to retrieve the text of those post IDs which are having the tag `B or D` what will be the easiest way to achieve this ?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to perform a [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operation.

Comment: can I use OR condition with more than one item in the tags list ?

Comment: You could do so, or you could just use the [IN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference) keyword in the filter expression to compare against a an enumerated list of values. (I am not sure though whether your `tags` is a **Map** or a **List**)

Comment: It could be anything, In this structure I have shown it like a Map but that will be fine if I use a List instead.

Comment: Something similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/34349180/2811189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed on comments, if you maintain the `tags` attribute as **DynamoDB list data type**, you can use **`CONTAINS`** with **`OR`** operator to check to filter the posts which has tags `B or D`.

**Sample params for Scan API:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName: "post",
    FilterExpression: "contains (tags, :tag1) OR  contains (tags, :tag2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tag1": 'B',
        ":tag2": 'D'
    }
};
```

**Full code:-**

The below code uses local DynamoDB.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
    credentials: creds
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName: "post",
    FilterExpression: "contains (tags, :tag1) OR  contains (tags, :tag2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":tag1": 'B',
        ":tag2": 'D'
    }
};

console.log("Scanning Post table.");
docClient.scan(params, onScan);

function onScan(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Scan succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function (printItem) {
            console.log("Item :", JSON.stringify(printItem));
        });

        if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            docClient.scan(params, onScan);
        }
    }
}
```